# Does a.e. convergence in product measure imply a.e. convergence in original measures?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let

- $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathcal B, \nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measure spaces, and $(E, | \cdot |)$ a Banach space.
- $\mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$ the product $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$.
- $\lambda = \mu \otimes \nu$ be the product measure of $\mu$ and $\nu$.
- $f, f_n \in E^{X \times Y}$ be $\lambda$-measurable for all $n$ such that $f_n \to f$ $\lambda$-a.e.

I would like to ask whether below statement is true.

> For $\mu$-a.e. $x \in X$, for $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$, $f_n (x, y) \to f(x, y)$.

**My attempt:** If not, there exists $A \in \mathcal A$ such that $\mu(A) >0$ and that $$\forall (x \in A) \exists (B_x \in \mathcal B) \big [ \nu(B_x) > 0 \text{ and } \forall (y \in B_x) [f_n (x, y) \not \to f (x, y) ] \big ].$$

Let $Z := \cup_{x \in A} \{x\} \times B_x$. The answer would be positive if $Z \in \mathcal A \otimes \mathcal B$ with $\lambda(Z) > 0$. But I'm unable to prove it.

---

**Update:** The statement is not very clear. The clearer one is

> There is a null set $N_X \in \mathcal A$ such that for each $x \in N_X^c := (N_X)^c$, there exists a null set $N_{Y,x} \in \mathcal B$ such that for all $y \in N_{Y, x}^c := (N_{Y,x})^c$, $f_n(x,y) \to f(x,y)$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set on which $f_n\not\to f$. Note that
$$
0=(\mu\times\nu)(A)=\int \nu(A_x)\,d\mu(x)=\int\mu(A^y)\, d\nu(y),
$$
where $A_x$ and $A^y$ are the $x$- and $y$-sections of $A$. It means that for $\mu$-almost all $x$, $\nu(A_x)=0$ and for $\nu$-almost all $y$, $\mu(A^y)=0$.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. I would mention that the equation above follows from the existence and uniqueness of product measures

Comment: If the null sets for both measures are allowed to have a dependence to each other, then this is clearly the answer. But somehow this is just trivially rewriting the definition of a.e.-convergence w.r.t. $\lambda$.

Comment: @Falrach I have updated my thread to have clearer statement.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you asked for, but in my understanding - I understood your statement as that the null sets for $\mu$ and $\nu$ can not depend on each other - the following is a counterexample.

Let $E=X=Y = \Bbb R$. Choose the $\sigma$-algebras as Borel-$\sigma$-algebras and take $\mu$ and $\nu$ as Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$.

We can define the sequence of functions

$$f_n (x,y) := \begin{cases} 0 &: x\neq y\\ (-1)^n &: x=y\end{cases}$$

Clearly the functions do not converge pointwise, but they converge a.e. since $\mu \otimes \nu (\Delta) = 0$ with $\Delta = \{(x,x) : x\in \Bbb R\}$.

Now assume that for $\mu$-a.e. $x\in X$ and $\nu$-a.e. $y\in Y$ we had $f_n(x,y)\to f(x,y)$, where the only possible function $f$ is $f\equiv 0$.

It exist thus a set $N_X \subset X$ and $N_Y\subset Y$ such that $f_n(x,y) \to 0$ for every $(x,y) \in ( X\setminus N_X )\times (Y\setminus N_Y)$ and $\mu (N_X) = 0$ and $\nu (N_Y)=0$.

Since $f_n (x,x)$ diverges for any $x\in \Bbb R$ we have that $(X\setminus N_X ) \cap (Y\setminus N_Y) =\emptyset$, which means that $X \setminus N_X \subset N_Y$ and $Y\setminus N_Y \subset N_X$. This is a contradiction since $X\setminus N_X$ and $Y\setminus N_Y$ can not be null sets.